# array_push using multidimensional array in ZEND Framework

Tags: php, arrays, function, zend-framework, multidimensional-array

I have a hierarchy like `parent->child1->child2...` and so on

And the main thing in this, developing of an array is only one's while insert/editing (I am working on zend).

Now, I want prevent updating my `parent_id` while in edit case of `child`.

I have used this, but its not working well

```
$data = array('fieldname'=>$request['name'],
              'fieldname2'=>$request['xyz']
);

if(!isset(update)){    
  array_push($data,'parent_id'=>$request['parent_id']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `array_push()` in this context.

Just do this

```
if(!isset(update)){    
  $data['parent_id']=$request['parent_id'];
}
```